# SQL Server: Get time duration based on continues values of a column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, group-by, data-partitioning

I Have a table Like This

```
ID           VehicleID             Time               EngineStatus
--          ----------      ------------------     ----------------
0              0001          1/11/2016 00:00              off
0              0002          1/11/2016 00:10              off
0              0003          1/11/2016 00:10              off
0              0001          1/11/2016 00:10              ON
0              0001          1/11/2016 00:11              ON
0              0003          1/11/2016 00:20              off
0              0002          1/11/2016 00:15              off
0              0001          1/11/2016 00:11              off
0              0001          1/11/2016 00:12              off
0              0001          1/11/2016 00:20              ON
0              0001          1/11/2016 00:25              ON
```

I want to get EngineStatus of every vehicle and it duration.
I need a query that results like this

```
     Start              End                 Status        VehileID
---------------    --------------          --------      ----------
1/11/2016 00:00    1/11/2016 00:10           OFF            0001
1/11/2016 00:10    1/11/2016 00:11           ON             0001
1/11/2016 00:11    1/11/2016 00:12           Off            0001
1/11/2016 00:20    1/11/2016 00:25           ON             0001

1/11/2016 00:10    1/11/2016 00:15           OFF            0002

1/11/2016 00:10    1/11/2016 00:20           OFF            0003
```

I think somehow I have to group the data based on continues values of a column and then get first and last row from each group.

Comment: Can you include the version of SQL Server you are using?  2012, and higher, include additional options not available in the earlier versions.

Comment: I *think* your question has been downvoted because it doesn't include an example of what you have tried so far (but it's hard to tell because the downvoters haven't included comments).

Comment: It is SQL server 2008R2
Thank you for your time in advance

Comment: In your example should vehicle 0001 be off from 00:12 to 00:20.  Should there be a record returned for this, creating an unbroken sequence from the first logged time until the last?

Comment: Yes there should be data for that time- but it may is not delivered to server yet.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT MIN([Time]) AS [Start], MAX([Time]) AS [End],
       EngineStatus, VehicleID
FROM (
  SELECT VehicleID, [Time], EngineStatus,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY VehicleID ORDER BY [Time]) -
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY VehicleID, EngineStatus
                            ORDER BY [Time]) AS grp
  FROM mytable ) AS t
GROUP BY VehicleID, EngineStatus, grp
```

`grp` identifies slices of *consecutive* records having the same `VehicleID, EngineStatus` values.

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
;with data_tbl as (
    select 
        [VehicleID], 
        [Time], 
        [EngineStatus],
        dense_rank() over(partition by [VehicleID] order by [VehicleID], [Time]) rnk
    from tbl    
)
select
    t1.[Time] Start,
    t2.[Time] End,
    t1.[EngineStatus] Status,
    t1.[VehicleID] VehileID   
from data_tbl t1
join data_tbl t2 
on t1.[VehicleID] = t2.VehicleID 
and t1.rnk = t2.rnk - 1
and t1.[EngineStatus] = t2.[EngineStatus]
order by t1.[VehicleID], t1.[Time]
```